# Navigate to record detail page from the lightning community builder

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community-builder

I want to redirect the record to its detail page when onclick from the component. 
 `<a href="{!'/'+resultWrap.resultId}" class="slds-card__header-link slds-truncate"  >
        <span class="slds-text-heading_small" style="{!'color:'+v.textColor}">
                           {!resultWrap.resultHeader} 
        </span>
</a>`  so i specified the ID in href.

It works fine in lightning component, but in the Community builder when I click the record  am getting an error message (invalid page)

Comment: your url path is incorrect, check your community url and compare

Comment: Am sorry can you elaborate, I didn't get it. From the lightning component page when I click the record (link) it is redirected to detail page

Answer (score 2):

Really, you shouldn't be using direct links like that to navigate in Lightning. You should use a `e.force:navigateToSObject` event. The domain for the community URL will change depending on whether you are in sandbox or production; and whether you're using a custom domain.

The path can change based on options selected in Community Builder e.g. a Contact record can be /mycommunity/s/contact/0035E00000766I7QAI/firstname-lastname today, but then it can change in community builder to become /mycommunity/s/my-contact/0035E00000766I7QAI/firstname-lastname tomorrow.

I use a custom component instead of  links, and that sorts out the whole mess for me.

Link.cmp

```
<aura:component access="global">

    <aura:attribute name="type" type="String" default="a" />
    <aura:attribute name="class" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="relativeUrl" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="id" type="String" />

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.type == 'button'}">
        <button id="{!v.id}" class="{!v.class}" onclick="{!c.onClick}">
            {!v.body}
        </button>
        <aura:set attribute="else">
            <a id="{!v.id}" class="{!v.class}" onclick="{!c.onClick}">
                {!v.body}
            </a>
        </aura:set>
    </aura:if>

</aura:component>
```

LinkController.js:

```
({
    onClick : function(component, event, helper) {
        var recordId = component.get('v.recordId');
        var navEvt;
        if(recordId) {
            navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
            navEvt.setParam("recordId", recordId);
        } else {
            navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
            navEvt.setParam("url", component.get('v.relativeUrl'));
        }
        navEvt.fire();
    }
})
```

Which would make your code:

```
<c:Link recordId="{!resultWrap.resultId}" class="slds-card__header-link slds-truncate"  >
        <span class="slds-text-heading_small" style="{!'color:'+v.textColor}">
                           {!resultWrap.resultHeader} 
        </span>
</c:Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

invalid page means that the url which you are referencing does not exist, for example, if  your href is referencing:

```
domain.instance.force.com/communityname/001f40000033BrDAAU
```

you will get an invalid page, look at the actual url when you open record details in communities and modify your href accordingly.

Comment: <a href="{!'/'+resultWrap.resultId}" class="slds-card__header-link slds-truncate"  >
                  <span class="slds-text-heading_small" style="{!'color:'+v.textColor}">{!resultWrap.resultHeader}</span>
                </a>  This is my code which i refered before